# Getting bind exception while starting apache nifi

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-nifi

I am using nifi 1.12.0 with java 11. Nifi was working properly but suddenly nifi started getting hanged then i stopped the nifi and restarted nifi process. Nifi stopped successfully but when i try to start i am getting below error.

```
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /home/nifi-1.12.0

Bootstrap Config File: /home/nifi-1.12.0/conf/bootstrap.conf

Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:349)
        at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.NiFiListener.start(NiFiListener.java:38)
        at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.start(RunNiFi.java:1082)
        at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.main(RunNiFi.java:236)
```

I googled about this error and try to find out what is running on nifi port using below command and got noting

```
netstat -na | grep LISTEN | grep 8080
lsof -n -i4TCP:8080
lsof -i:8080
```

Then i restarted the server but still getting same error. Please help me how to solve this issue.
Below is nifi config.

```
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true
```

Below is boostrap.log

```
2021-09-28 18:17:31,004 INFO [main] o.a.n.b.NotificationServiceManager Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
2021-09-28 18:17:31,009 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
2021-09-28 18:17:31,009 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
2021-09-28 18:17:31,009 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
2021-09-28 18:17:31,013 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Runtime Java version: 11.0.11
```

Comment: what does ps -ef says?

Comment: not able to find any process which is related to nifi

Comment: what happens if you set `nifi.web.http.host=` to `nifi.web.http.host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: is there java process running ..nifi will have a java process running..

Comment: Try `netstat -na | grep 8080` and check the output. There might be other states a TCP socket be in.

Comment: `ss` should be used in place of `netstat` these days

Comment: @Sdairs i have trying to set 0.0.0.0 but it is not working

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra no process running on port 8080

Comment: @TahaNaqvi there is not java process running on system